# Calling an event when touching a ScrollView item

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to call an event when I press on an item inside this `ScrollView`?

```
let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
    return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
        deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)}
        editMethod={()=> this.editMethod(key, val)} />
});

<ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}> {notes} </ScrollView>
```

Note:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Note extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            
                {this.props.val.date}
                {this.props.val.note}

```
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>Del</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.editMethod} style={styles.editNote}>
                <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>Edit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
note: {
    position: 'relative',
    padding: 20,
    paddingRight: 100,
    borderBottomWidth:2,
    borderBottomColor: '#ededed'
},
noteText: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: '#0000FF'
},
noteDelete: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    padding: 10,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
},
editNote: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    padding: 10,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 70
},
noteDeleteText: {
    color: 'white'
},
});
```

Comment: are you passing a props to Note component ?

Comment: key and val. Let me place the Note component in the question

Comment: There you go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your all items under [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) in which you like to get an event:

```
 <TouchableOpacity               
      onPress={() => { 
                alert('Pressed')
      }}>
// Keep your element which you like to tap
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can refer the [react-native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/touchableopacity.html) for more reference.

Comment: If I do this, the event will apply if I press the ScrollView, not the item inside it.

Comment: wrap it inside a view. It'll work when clicked on anywhere inside the view. I don't prefer using buttons, so i use a combination of touchableHightlight with view and text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
    return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
        deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote.bind(key)}
        editMethod={()=> this.editMethod.bind(key, val)} />
});
```